# Load only certain language files (arrays) in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-7

I wanted to know if there is any way in Laravel (7) to load only the language files of certain zones/sections. By this I mean that, for example, if a user enters in Users section, load only the "users" and "general" language files.

As far as I know, Laravel seems to always load all the files, which I consider unnecessary. Especially when the number of indexes in the arrays start to become large, I think a solution is needed in this way.

I know that in other Frameworks like CodeIngiter this option is available, but in Laravel I have searched several times for something similar and I can't find anything that solves this problem.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I think Laravel is not provide that type of functionality single lanaguage file at time of load any page.

Comment: @NikuNjRathod looks like that, but at the same time It sounds unbelievable that a framework like Laravel doesn't have this option.

Comment: Yes, I am agree with you Laravel is not provide that type of functionality. If any type of solution are found then I will post here.